# Accessing form elements in django views

Tags: django, forms

this is my html form :

```
<form method="post" name="crossDayForm" action='{% url 'crossDayGolden' %}'>
    Query : <input type="text" name="query" required>
    <input type="date" name="date1" required>
    <input type="date" name="date2" required>
    <input type=submit value="Go"  >
  </form>
```

I want to know how to get query,date1,date2 in my views?

Comment: Follow this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/

Comment: refer to this question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225601/django-form-to-query-database-models

Answer (score 0):

you can access this variable doing:

**views.py**

```
def proccess(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       date1 = request.POST.get('date1')
       date2 = request.POST.get('date2')
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer official [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form).

You can access form element by  `form.fields['name'].`